# Zoom in zoom out div issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my DIV

```
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
```

and this is my CSS

```
div.apple_overlay {
    display: none;
    background: url('img/noisebg.png') #3b3d40 repeat top left;
    width: 702px;
    height: 306px;
    margin-top: 91px;
    direction:rtl;
    padding-left:0px;    
    font-size: 11px;
    position: static;
    float:inherit;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

When I zoom in the DIV goes to right and when I zoom out the DIV goes left.. Can some one address me how to fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: i'm pretty sure nothing will be displayed.... `display: none;`

Comment: In order to get a better response, you will have to provide more code or put your work on jsfiddle or something. Other elements may be affecting that div. But even as pattmorter put it, that div won't display with the code you've posted.